# Create SMS message for user and close when they hit send

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an option for a user to select a contact, open up messaging with a pre-populated but editable message. When the user hits send, I'd like for messaging to close and return to my app. Here's my current code to send the SMS:

```
Intent smsMsg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNum));
smsMsg.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello friend.");
startActivity(smsMsg);
```

I tried startActivityForResult hoping the send would get me back yo onActivityResult and it doesn't. What are my options for returning back to my current activity after the user hits send? Or is it even feasible?

Comment: You cannot kill external activity, once you called it. User must hit "exit". I guess, to have total control on that, you will have to handle sending process yourself and request suitable rights for that in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question of 
[Return to Activity after action completed in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375561/return-to-activity-after-action-completed-in-android)

just need to add

`sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);`

Comment: i am trying this with android 4.4.3 and hangouts but "exit_on_sent" does nothing.