# start the sms intent, send message and close out

Tags: android, android-intent

i am open up the default SMS app and populate a message with users here. the problem is after sending the message i have to hit back twice before it goes back to my application. i'd like for the app to close out after they send the message. what is the fix for this?

```
String uri = "smsto:" + builder.toString();
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some message");
smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

also: i tried using the starActivityForResult but the onActivityResult callback is called IMMEDIATELY after the sms intent is opened, not when the message is sent, so it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Re check your activity's launch mode, if the activity is `singleInstance`, the callback would be fired IMMEDIATELY when the `startActivityForResult` be called

Comment: there is no launch mode set, whatever default is.

Comment: did you define it in your manifest`android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: Then I have no idea about it. Does this work for you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375561/return-to-activity-after-action-completed-in-android

Comment: i've searched SO extensively about this and wasn't able to find a working solution (that link included)