# Dismiss SMS activity/screen after sending sms in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sms, back

I cannot find a way to dismiss the SMS screen/activity after sending SMS successfully.

At the moment i can send SMS, but to come back to my app i have to press back.

I want the SMS screen to be dismissed AND control to come to my app automatically after sending the SMS.

This is the code i am using:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "074********; 074********");
    Intent smsSIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    smsSIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "iconference sms");
    startActivity(smsSIntent);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return to Activity after action completed in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375561/return-to-activity-after-action-completed-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use exit on sent to return back to your application.

```
sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
```

Comment: This also dismisses the parent `Activity` it was called from

Comment: Works, but always returns RESULT_CANCELLED

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `activity` in your `application` which sends `SMS` then you can call `finish()` from your `activity` to exit from `activity`. By using built-in `SMS` screen you cannot exit the screen until you do it by your self. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm) is a good `tutorial` for sending `SMS` from your `application`.