# How to close the SMS Activity after sending the SMS successfully

Tags: android

I am using "SMS Intent" to send the SMS, I am not able to exit the SMS screen after successful completion of the SMS. here is the source code.

```
//Sending SMS to multiple phone numbers
public void sendSms(Context context, String text, String numbers) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("sms:" + numbers)
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
    intent.putExtra("address", numbers);
    intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
            intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
    } else {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    }

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I close the SMS activity/screen?
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Strange question asked just 1 min ago and already it have 4 upvotes

Comment: This can be a bigger problem now because google is not allowing sms permission like  before

Comment: I am just using SMS Intent, this doesn't require SEND_SMS permission

Comment: You can't .. Try `context.startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));`. This way the other app will open in new Stack and you will able to go to your app from Recent apps .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to close the SMS Activity after sending the SMS successfully

Try this:

```
private int INVITE_COMPLETED = 1;

String message = "Hello";
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + "Mobile Number"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
startActivityForResult(sendIntent, INVITE_COMPLETED);
```

Above code completely worked for me. After sending SMS it returns my activity.

You may also take a look:
[i found solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15251956/6176507)

I've tried by using your code. Here it's work fine.

Below Your Code:

```
public void sendSms(Context context, String text, String numbers) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("sms:" + numbers);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
    intent.putExtra("address", numbers);
    intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
            intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
    } else {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    }

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, INVITE_COMPLETED);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For multiple numbers below code i used & it works fine:

```
 sendSms(MainActivity.this, "Hello", "Num1;Num2");
```

Comment: I already tried it but it's not worked for me. Is there any code required in onActivityResult???  @Md. Zakir Hossain

Comment: i've tried by your code. My side it's work fine

Comment: hey  @Md. Zakir Hossain!!! it's worked for me also...Thank you...

Comment: it is not working in higher versions of android ex: 7.0 and above versions

Comment: @M Neelima, i've checked it and found that you can't do it in higher version of android like 7 or above. You have to "Use the Back button to return to the PhoneMessaging app" otherwise you have to implement "Send an SMS message from within an app" Ref: https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-phone-sms-course/content/Lesson%202/2_p_sending_sms_messages.html

Comment: This worked for me as well in Android 8. However as you all have said, you have to press back button to return. I do not think there is any solution if the message is sent or errored. Google is making it very difficult for app developers. Send SMS could have been done through the app itself but they wont allow it, which makes no sense. I hope they introduce a feature in newer releases.